# Extending a vector so its projection match another vector's length, there's a name for that?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors, inner-products, projection

**My Problem**

I'm a game developer, and I had a problem yesterday in which I needed to extend a vector $\vec{v}$ so its projection into $\vec{w}$ was equal to $||\vec{w}||$.

[image]
*(Illustrating the Problem)*

**How I solved the problem**

By using the projection of $\vec{w}$ into $\vec{v}$, its perpendicular distance, and a bit of trigonometry, I was able to get to this formula:
$$vNewLength=\frac{||\vec{w}||^2}{projection}$$

[image: Illustrating how I solved the problem]
*(Illustrating how I solved the problem)*

*PS.: The final formula is slightly wrong on the picture, sorry, it should be $||\vec{w}||^2$ instead of $\vec{v}$*

**There's a name for that?**

I would like to know if this is a known operation between vectors, and what's the name so I can look it up to expand my knowledge on the topic.

**Edit (29/May/2023).:** For future reference, I discovered that another way of approaching this problem is to use secant:
$$x=hypotenuse*\sec(\alpha)=||\vec{w}||*\frac{||\vec{w}||}{projection}=\frac{||\vec{w}||^2}{projection}$$

Comment: Exactly! I already got this formula that seems to work as I need it to, but if that's a known operation I can refer to it in the code, maybe get another perspective on the problem by looking it up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there's a name for this operation, but the math can be simplified using the [dot product/inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). In a 2D cartesian coordinate system, the dot product can be calculated by $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w} = v_x w_x + v_y w_y.$

The dot product $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}$ is equal to the length of the projection of $\vec{v}$ onto $\vec{w}$ multiplied by the length of $\vec{w}$. So, the length of the projection of $\vec{v}$ onto $\vec{w}$ is equal to $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}/||\vec{w}||.$ We want a scalar $k$ to scale $\vec{v}$ so that
$$k\vec{v}\cdot\left(\frac{\vec{w}}{||\vec{w}||}\right) = ||\vec{w}||.$$
This results in
$$k = \frac{||\vec{w}||^2}{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}}.$$
Finally, the new length of $\vec{v}$ is $k||\vec{v}||.$

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks for sharing, I really appreciate it! :)